# Bounds for rank of product of two matrices $A$ and $B$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, numerical-linear-algebra

How to establish the rank inequalities
$$
\mbox{rank}(A) + \mbox{rank}(B) - n \leq \mbox{rank}(A B) \leq \min\{ \mbox{rank}(A), \mbox{rank}(B) \} \tag{1}
$$
where $A$ and $B$ are real matrices of sizes $m \times n$, $n \times p$, respectively.

I checked the archives of this forum and the second inequality has been proved.

To recapitulate the arguments, first we note that $AB$ consists of vectors of the form
$$
A b_1, A b_2, \ldots, A b_p
$$
where $b_1, b_2, \ldots, b_p$ are the column vectors of $B$.

Thus, the column span of $A B$ is contained in the column span of $A$.

This shows that
$$
\mbox{rank}(A B) \leq \mbox{rank}(A).
$$

Next, we define the matrices
$$
C = A^T, D = B^T
$$
and note that
$$
\mbox{rank}(D C) \leq \mbox{rank}(D)
$$

Since a matrix $P$ and its transpose ($P^T$) have the same rank, it follows that
$$
\mbox{rank}(C^T D^T) \leq \mbox{rank}(D^T)
$$
or
$$
\mbox{rank}(A B) \leq \mbox{rank}(B)
$$

Hence, we showed that
$$
\mbox{rank}(A B) \leq \min\{ \mbox{rank}(A), \mbox{rank}(B) \}
$$

(This is not any new proof - I only recounted ideas presented in this forum.)

My query is how to prove the lower bound given in (1) for $\mbox{rank}(A B)$.

In other words, how to prove:
$$
\mbox{rank}(A) + \mbox{rank}(B) - n \leq \mbox{rank}(A B) \tag{2}
$$

I tried some examples, but I am not getting any intuition for it.

Your suggestions are welcome.

Comment: Do you know the rank-nullity theorem?

Comment: Yes, I saw the answer - It is clear now, thanks.

Comment: Sylvester's inequality is a special case of Frobenius inequality: $\mbox{rank}(A B C) \geq \mbox{rank}(A B) + \mbox{rank}(B C) - \mbox{rank}(B)$. This result is true for complex matrices $A, B, C$ of appropriate dimensions.